# Combine Template for Perfect Forwarding and Tempate for arbitrary value_type

Tags: c++, templates, stl, move-semantics, sfinae

1. I have this function template `foo` that takes any STL container that contains `int`:

   ```
   template <typename ContainerType, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename ContainerType::value_type, int>::value, int> = 0>
   void foo(ContainerType const& list)
   { /* */ }
   ```
2. And I have this function template `bar` that takes a `std::vector<int>` and transform it for perfect forwarding (or reference forwarding, whatever you may call it):

   ```
   template <typename ContainerType, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<ContainerType>, std::vector<int>>::value, int> = 0>
   void bar(ContainerType&& list)
   { /* */ }
   ```

---

```
int main(void)
{
    std::initializer_list<int> list{1, 2, 3};
    std::vector<int> vec{1, 2, 3};

    foo(list);  // OK
    foo(vec);  // OK
    foo(std::vector<int>{4, 5, 6});  // OK, but copy-semantics

    bar(vec);  // OK
    bar(std::vector<int>{4,5,6});  // OK
    bar(list);  // ERROR
}
```

I want to combine these two into one, to get a template function that accepts STL Containers with `value_type` `int` and prepare them for perfect forwarding. How I can accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just combine your conditions. We want a function that takes a forwarding-reference:

```
template <class C, class = std::enable_if_t<???> >
void quux(C&& container);
```

And you want that the `value_type` of the underlying `container` is `int`. Let's throw that into its own trait for readability:

```
template <class C>
using is_int_container = std::is_same<typename C::value_type, int>;
```

Now, can't just do `is_int_container<C>` because `C` at the moment can be a reference or reference to `const`. But we can just fix that with [`std::decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
template <class C, class = std::enable_if_t<is_int_container<std::decay_t<C>>::value >>
void quux(C&& container);
```

Comment: Works wonderfully, thanks, but do you know, why it won't accept braced-init-lists? I assumed they would be would be transformed to `std::initializer_list<int>`, however it seems they are not.

Comment: @hgiesel Wrong assumption. You can't deduce a type from a braced-init-list (it doesn't have a type). You can just add an overload taking `std::initializer_list<int>`.